# diff time r studio is not giving the outcome properly

Tags: r, difftime

Im trying to calculate the difftime in minutes between two columns and the results seems to be not right.

| BLOCK_DATE_TIME.x | a1_0 | diff |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-04-26 19:07:00 | 2019-04-27 09:00:00 | 773 |
| 2019-08-27 08:30:00 | 2019-08-27 09:00:00 | -30 |

the code to calculate diff is the following:

`test$diff <- difftime(test$a1_0,test$BLOCK_DATE_TIME.x,units = "mins")`

The desire outcome is for the first line 833 and for the second 30.

Thanks in advance

Comment: When I run the code (and convert to `POSIXt` class), I get 833 and 30. It would be helpful if you provided unambiguous sample data: the best here would be to paste the output from `dput(test)` (or some row-subset), since it shows *exactly* what you have, not just how it appears on the console (which can be significantly different).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that the columns are not Datetime class. If we convert to `POSIXct`, it works as expected

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
test1 <- test %>% 
      mutate(across(c(BLOCK_DATE_TIME.x, a1_0), ymd_hms),
         diff = difftime(a1_0, BLOCK_DATE_TIME.x, units = "mins"))
test1
#    BLOCK_DATE_TIME.x                a1_0     diff
#1 2019-04-26 19:07:00 2019-04-27 09:00:00 833 mins
#2 2019-08-27 08:30:00 2019-08-27 09:00:00  30 mins
```

#### data

```
test <- structure(list(BLOCK_DATE_TIME.x = c("2019-04-26 19:07:00", 
"2019-08-27 08:30:00"
), a1_0 = c("2019-04-27 09:00:00", "2019-08-27 09:00:00")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks it as to do with UTC vs BCS times. I was very frustrating try to solve this. thank you all